# Git Checkout Speed - Under the Hook

Tags: file-io, filesystems, file-copying

NOTE: This is not about how to use Git.. This is about under the hood working.

Can you explain how Git can checkout files so quickly from one branch to another?
For example, giving I have two branches, each branch has 10Gb of files...
I am able to checkout from one branch to the other in under a second.

When I checkout, the new files are on disk and ready to go.
However, if I was to delete 10gb and then restore 10gb of files it would take a few minutes.

I understand the basics of Git Objects and how Commit'ish, Trees and blobs work however, when checking out a diferent branch, the file needs to restored from the blobs and any existing untracked files removed. How is this happening so quickly???

I am assuming this is done using some form of HDD pointers..
I read over the Git code but my C skills are rusty.

Comment: There are some tutorials available that go into details about this. I'll try to dig one up.

Comment: it depends how many differences there are between branches. Git only checks out files which are different.  So, if all files are different, git will some take time to switch.